# Bound probability with another probability of maximum value

Tags: probability-inequalities

If $X$ and $Y$ are random variables, and we know that maximum value of $Y$ is $Y_{\max}$ which is just a constant.
Can we state the following?:
$\Pr[X+Y > t] \leq \Pr[X+Y_{\max} > t]$
where $t$ is just a positive constant. My intuition says that this is true because I suppose $\{X+Y > t\} \subseteq \{X+Y_{\max} > t\}$ but I am not sure.

Comment: Hard to argue with your impeccable logic!